# Cygwin can't access to environment variable

Tags: variables, cygwin, environment

I am a beginner in this.  I just install Cygwin.  I have problem in access all my environment variable.

e.g.
prior to install cygwin, i am using cmd prompt.  I added a variable named "shotcut" with value "c:\my_doc\".  In the c:\my_doc\, i create a shotcut.bat.  The content is cd /dc:\my_doc.

Then, i added %shotcut% into a variable called "PATH".  When i use cmd, once i type shotcut, it will move to c:\my_doc\

However, using cygwin terminal, i type shotcut and pops out command not found.  What can i do in order to use all my environment variable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin imports environment variables, so if you have one called "shotcut" as you say, the equivalent var called `$shotcut` should exist in your Cygwin environment. Doing `echo $shotcut` should output the path you set in your OS.

Alternatively, you could run the `env` command, which will list the full set of vars currently set in your shell session, and look for your variable in there.

Comment: that is useful information you provided but you didn't respond to the question that how to make it run command which are available in PATH env